# How can i uninstall multiple programs using single uninstall? (Sequential uninstall)

Tags: c#, installshield, excel-addins, uninstallation

I am developing an excel add-in in c#.

I had created MSI package for installation using InstallShield limited edition.

During this package creation, I have to add files (**.vsto and setup.exe) and "Application Files"** folder from published folder in 3rd step (Application files) and in the last step of this process I choose to launch an application and gave the path to the setup.exe file.

I have to do the last step otherwise, it doesn't install as excel add-in and won't show in add-ins menu.

The real problem for me is I have to uninstall both "the MSI package" and "VSTO" but I want to make it single click uninstall. when the MSI package uninstalled, it will automatically uninstall the .vsto.

if we can do this uninstall process manually using some kind of c# scripting code will also helpful. How can I perform sequential uninstallation?